# Multiple variables recognised as parsing error

Tags: haskell

Why am I getting a parse error on "a b c d"?

```
computeNumbers :: Float -> Int -> Int -> Float -> Float 
computerNumbers (a b c d) = ((pi * a/2 ^2) * 0.002 + (((pi * a/2 ^2) * 0.001) * b) + c * 0.55) * 1.5 + (if d > 0 then d * 0.9 else d)
```

I have tried everything from deleting every space between words to make sure that I did not use TAB by mistake and rearrange the brackets. Nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the parentheses entirely.

Without the parens you are binding the names to the four arguments. With the parens you are matching a *single argument* with a pattern that does not match a `Float`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I will keep this in mind. It worked, but now b and c are having the same issue... a and d are fine apparently. Not so sure about d actually.

Comment: What issue? Did you write `computerNumbers a b c d = ...` as suggested? How are you *calling* the function?

Comment: It's not so much that `(a b c d)` does not match a `Float`, as the fact that `(a b c d)` is not a valid pattern at all. (For example, you can't use `(l_or_r x)` to match an `Either a b` value; you have to match against `Left` or `Right` explicitly.)